# Tools for upper/lower case consistency in CMake source

Tags: coding-style, cmake, lint

CMake commands are valid in lower, upper, and mixed case. Mixing all of those together in one file however reduces the readability of the CMake code.

Is there a tool for automatically correcting this kind of stylistic inconsistencies?

Answer (score 13):

The answer by steveire links to the right resources, but let me explain explicitly in case those links vanish.

CMake command are case insensitive but lower case is recommended according to CMake developer Brad King in 2012:

> Ancient CMake versions required upper-case commands.  Later command
>   names became case-insensitive.  Now the preferred style is lower-case.

The shell code that allowed to convert my project `CMakeLists.txt` file to lower case was inspired by the code behind the links of steveire's answer:

```
cmake --help-command-list \
    | while read c; do
        echo 's/\([^a-zA-Z_]\|^\)'"$c"'\(\s*\)(/\1'"$c"'\2(/gI'
    done > convert.sed
git ls-files -z -- '*CMakeLists.txt' | xargs -0 sed -i -f convert.sed
```

It has the following improvements:

- `grep -v "cmake version"` is not required anymore because it seems that the `--help-command-list` output does not contain that anymore
- the original regex contained a `\b` which made it not match any thing with GNU sed 4.2.2
- instead, the cmake command must be preceded by a non-letter/underscore or the start of the line
- instead of converting the cmake command to all upper case, make the regex case insensitive. This will also find and convert mixed-case occurrences like `Find_Package`.
- there are no parts specific to the cmake codebase. Modify to fit yours. This simple construct was enough for mine.

Answer (score 5):

Adapt this to your needs:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=77543bd

See also:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=9db31162

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out `cmake-format`:

- https://pypi.org/project/cmake-format/
- https://github.com/cheshirekow/cmake_format