# How to ensure consistent coding style for CMakeLists.txt and FindXXX.cmake

Tags: c++, coding-style, cmake

There are clang-format etc to ensure a consistent coding style for .cpp and .h files among different developers.

But how can I ensure consistent coding style in `CMake` for CMakeLists.txt and FindXXX.cmake written from different developers?

The main rules I want to enforce is consistent indention/space, upper/lower case consistency, 80 character per line constraint

Comment: Off topic question here, sorry!

Comment: why is this question off topic?

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic either, but anyway - I can't say I've ever heard of such a script/tool for CMake code.

Comment: Some of the very basic things I ensure with [`.editorconfig`](http://editorconfig.org/). Can you give an example of the rules you want to enforce? There are some specific solutions like [Tools for upper/lower case consistency in CMake source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839458/tools-for-upper-lower-case-consistency-in-cmake-source) or [`cmake-lint`](https://github.com/richq/cmake-lint).

Comment: Because looking for external resources (like books, tools) is off-topic.

Comment: @Florian Excellent answer! I would accept your answer if it's not a comment. The main rules I want to enforce is consistent indention/space, upper/lower case consistency (as you mentioned), 80 character per line constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

I don't know of a way to enforce `CMakeLists.txt` or other CMake script file's coding style in `CMake` itself. But there are editor extensions and format checkers available you can use:

- Some of the very basic things I ensure with [`.editorconfig`](http://editorconfig.org/)

  - You can configure: `indent_style`, `indent_size`, `tab_width`, `end_of_line`, `charset`, `trim_trailing_whitespace` and `insert_final_newline`
  - And there are EditorConfig plug-ins for a lot of editors available (if not supported out-of-the-box)
- With [cmake-lint](https://github.com/richq/cmake-lint) you can check/filter for a few more rules

  - It has filters for e.g. `convention/filename`, `linelength`, `package/consistency`, `readability/logic`, `readability/mixedcase`, `readability/wonkycase` or `syntax`
- And there is [Tools for upper/lower case consistency in CMake source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839458/tools-for-upper-lower-case-consistency-in-cmake-source)