# Do something for all targets

Tags: cmake

What is the best way to do additional stuff for all (binary) targets?

Examples:

- I want to check that each library name follows a pattern.
- I want to sign each executable.

I dont what the C/C++ developers to use nonstandard commands (like `add_library2`). I want them to use and learn the official CMake functions, but have them do additonal, project specific, stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in CMake functions `add_library` and `add_executable` can be overidden by defining CMake functions of the same name. E.g., to automatically sign all added executables add the following code:

```
function (add_executable _name)
    _add_executable(${ARGV})
    if (TARGET ${_name})
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${_name} POST_BUILD
            COMMAND sign_executable $<TARGET_FILE:${_name}>)
    endif()
endfunction()
```

The original built-in `add_executable` can be invoked by prefixing it with an underscore character. The same pattern can be applied to `add_library` to check the name of the library.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite any CMake command/function to extend its functionality, but please

#### Call Things by their Names

I strongly advocate to call the things by their names and not doing things implicitly. It will be easier for everybody using/maintaining/debugging your CMake based project.

If you want to sign your executable - and that's probably even platform specific - you create a function like `add_post_build_step_sign_executable()` which would add the appropriate post build steps:

```
add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
if (WIN32)
    add_post_build_step_sign_executable(MyExe)
endif()
```

And if you have to repeat yourself too often put that code snippet into a function like `my_project_add_signed_executable()` itself. It could still have the same parameter syntax as CMake's `add_executable()` command.

#### Runtime Checks vs. Static Code Analysis

Regarding library naming checks, I see this more like checking against your project's CMake script coding styles and would not use runtime checks for this.

For example you could use something like [`cmake-lint`](https://github.com/richq/cmake-lint) or your own external script to check for conformity.

#### References

- [How to frame the concept behind CMake?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299929/how-to-frame-the-concept-behind-cmake)
- [cmake: get add_library() names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427869/cmake-get-add-library-names)
- [How to ensure consistent coding style for CMakeLists.txt and FindXXX.cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467743/how-to-ensure-consistent-coding-style-for-cmakelists-txt-and-findxxx-cmake)