# Programmatically get all targets in a CMake project

Tags: cmake

I'd like to have one specific target be dependent on all the other added targets in my project. To say it in a different way - I'd like this target (say `lint`) to run after all the libraries and applications were built.

Is there a way in the top `CMakeLists.txt` file, where the `project` is specified, to get the list of all targets added by other `CMakeLists.txt` files in the directories added using [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html)? Then I can use the [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html) to specify the order. There is a [`BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html) property, but it only works on a directory level.

If there is some other way to achieve this, please let me know. I use CMake 3.14.

Comment: Have you checked the second answer for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434946/how-do-i-iterate-over-all-cmake-targets-programmatically) and both answers for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447627/do-something-for-all-targets)?

Comment: Thank you for the points. Yes, I did. There is mention of `BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS` but it only works for the current directory and not the full tree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not mention your CMake version, so I will assume `3.8` or better, for which this solution has been tested.

One possible solution is to iterate through all sub-directories in your project, and then apply `BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS` to each of them. For the sake of simplicity and readability, I have split this up into three different macros.

First, we need a way of recursively obtaining all sub-directories in the project. For this, we can use `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` with `LIST_DIRECTORIES` set to `ON`:

```
#
# Get all directories below the specified root directory.
#   _result     : The variable in which to store the resulting directory list
#   _root       : The root directory, from which to start.
#
macro(get_directories _result _root)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE dirs RELATIVE ${_root} LIST_DIRECTORIES ON ${_root}/*)
    foreach(dir ${dirs})
        if(IS_DIRECTORY ${dir})
            list(APPEND ${_result} ${dir})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro()
```

Secondly, we need a way to obtain all targets at a particular directory level. `DIRECTORY` takes an optional parameter, namely the directory you wish to query, which is key for this to work:

```
#
# Get all targets defined at the specified directory (level).
#   _result     : The variable in which to store the resulting list of targets.
#   _dir        : The directory to query for targets.
#
macro(get_targets_by_directory _result _dir)
    get_property(_target DIRECTORY ${_dir} PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
    set(_result ${_target})
endmacro()
```

Thirdly, we need another macro to tie all this together:

```
#
# Get all targets defined below the specified root directory.
#   _result     : The variable in which to store the resulting list of targets.
#   _root_dir   : The root project root directory
#
macro(get_all_targets _result _root_dir)
    get_directories(_all_directories ${_root_dir})
    foreach(_dir ${_all_directories})
        get_targets_by_directory(_target ${_dir})
        if(_target)
            list(APPEND ${_result} ${_target})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro()
```

Finally, here is how you can use it:

```
get_all_targets(ALL_TARGETS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

`ALL_TARGETS` should now be a list holding the names of every target created below the caller's directory level. Note that it does *not* include any targets created in the current `CMakeLists.txt`. For that, you can make an extra call to `get_targets_by_directory(ALL_TARGETS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})`.

Comment: awesome. Why did you have to check `if(IS_DIRECTORY ${dir})`? Isn't the `file()` only returns directories?

Comment: @ilya1725 No, it lists files too.

Comment: @ilya1725 `LIST_DIRECTORIES ON` merely instructs `file()` to also include directories, which is turned off by default when using `GLOB_RECURSE`.

Comment: When I try this code, no (relative) directory path is validated as a directory by `IS_DIRECTORY`. Thus, the macro `get_directories` do not really work. Maybe this is because I run CMake v3.18.2?

Comment: @Smartskaft2 Just tried this using CMake 3.19, and it seems to work as intented. Maybe try Ilya's solution (the other answer)?

Comment: @thomas_f Thank you for suggesting that, his answer worked fine for me.

Comment: This does not work for me (from within an included file): I get `get_property DIRECTORY scope provided but requested directory was not found`.

Answer (score 10):

For the future reference, I've ended up writing my own function instead of a macro. But the concept is the same as the accepted answer by @thomas_f.

Here is the code:

```
# Collect all currently added targets in all subdirectories
#
# Parameters:
# - _result the list containing all found targets
# - _dir root directory to start looking from
function(get_all_targets _result _dir)
    get_property(_subdirs DIRECTORY "${_dir}" PROPERTY SUBDIRECTORIES)
    foreach(_subdir IN LISTS _subdirs)
        get_all_targets(${_result} "${_subdir}")
    endforeach()

    get_directory_property(_sub_targets DIRECTORY "${_dir}" BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
    set(${_result} ${${_result}} ${_sub_targets} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```