# How do I get all of the targets that can be collected from the CmakeLists files in a project?

Tags: cmake, emacs

I was able to implement the logic of building, running and debugging a C++ project by passing the appropriate target functions configured in Cmake, but is there any way I can make the available targets display from Cmake? So I don't have to navigate through CmakeLists looking for the right target, but select it from the hint in the minibuffer, like with C-f?

```
(use-package projectile
  :config
  (projectile-mode +1))

(defun compile-project (target)
  (interactive "MEnter target name: ")
  (let ((build-dir (concat (projectile-project-root) "build/"))
        (compile-command (concat "cd " (projectile-project-root) " && cmake --build build --target " target)))
    (compile compile-command)))

(defun build-and-run-project (target)
  (interactive "MEnter target name: ")
  (compile-project target)
  (let ((build-dir (concat (projectile-project-root) "build/"))
        (compile-command (concat "cd " (projectile-project-root) " && cmake --build build --target " target " && " (projectile-project-root) "build/" target)))
    (compile compile-command)
    (async-shell-command (concat (projectile-project-root) "build/" target))))

(defun build-and-debug-project (target)
  (interactive "MEnter target name: ")
  (compile-project target)
  (let ((build-dir (concat (projectile-project-root) "build/"))
        (compile-command (concat "cd " (projectile-project-root) " && cmake --build build --target " target)))
    (compile compile-command)
    (gdb (concat "gdb -i=mi " (concat (projectile-project-root) "build/" target)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'build-and-run-project)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'build-and-debug-project)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'compile-project)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60211516/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37434946/11107541

Comment: @user I feel like you're giving me a fishing rod but I need a fish :3

Comment: unfortunately, I only have half the fishing rod because I don't know emacs