# How can I still use `make` while building with `ninja` when I use cmake to build a project?

Tags: cmake, makefile, ninja

Ninja as a build tool is much more advanced and helpful to debug than Make.

However typing `ninja` is much slower due to the right-right-right-right-left pattern while `make` is super fast with its right-left-right-left patter. I want to **type** `make` while it **builds** with `ninja`.

I have several projects which for historical reasons I have to use either make or ninja and I would like to normalize all to `make`.

I thought about using some shell tricks like `alias make='/bin/make || ninja'` but there are some cons:

1. They always depend on setting an environment variable, either by hand or on .bashrc. I don't want to do that.
2. An alias depends on knowing the location of the `make` and `ninja` binaries

So I was thinking about the easiest way to add *something* to my CMakeLists.txt files so it drops a `Makefile`, something like `drop_makefile()`. Even if the cost is to add that line into each of them in a project.

It would be easy enough to drop something like

```
all:
    ninja
```

which works fine if all you do is `make`.

However if I wanted to make a specific target that exists within ninja it would not work like `make tests`, which should translate into `ninja tests`.

Comment: You could use `configure_file` and just copy that sample `Makefile` to your build directories.  There's no magic one-lilner I'm aware of though.

Comment: What would the makefile be though? `make tests` does not work.

Comment: Why would an `alias` need to include the path to the `make` binary?

Comment: In all honesty this sounds a bit like an A-B problem. If the mere act of typing the start command for your build system has influence on your workflow then I assume you are using the build for syntax checking. Wouldn't it be wiser to switch to an IDE which supports continuous compiling so that you get your errors presented already inside the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to generate a `Makefile` containing all the targets known
to CMake, you can use the [`BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS.html) property. As this is a
directory property, you will need to traverse all directories of your project.
Luckily, the answers to
[Programmatically get all targets in a CMake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211516/programmatically-get-all-targets-in-a-cmake-project)
already show how this can be done. I tested with user [ilya1725](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224982/ilya1725)'s function `get_all_targets`.

All that's left is to iterate over the list and create Makefile syntax that calls `ninja` like this:

```cmake
function(drop_makefile)
    # Bail if CMake is already generating Makefiles
    if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Unix Makefiles")
        return()
    endif()

    # Function get_all_targets taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211516/programmatically-get-all-targets-in-a-cmake-project
    get_all_targets(_all_targets .)

    # Make magic "all" target the first one
    list(PREPEND _all_targets "all")
    foreach(_target IN LISTS _all_targets)
        string(APPEND _makefile ".PHONY: ${_target}\n${_target}:\n\tninja ${_target}\n")
    endforeach()
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Makefile ${_makefile})
endfunction(drop_makefile)
```

Call the function in your project's root directory and the result will be a `Makefile` containing all (non-imported) targets known to your project. I can't shake off the feeling this kind of defeats the purpose of CMake.

By the way, `make` will evaluate its options but not forward them to
`ninja`.
Something like `make -j32` will spawn 32 jobs but won't call `ninja -j32` under the hood.

Furthermore, CMake provides its own abstraction for the build tool as [`cmake --build`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project). This will call the right tool and digests some common options like `--jobs`. In this question, keystrokes are a factor and regarding them, this is right out of the question.

A much more simplistic solution would be to give each project its own configuration file `alias_make.sh` containing one of the following lines:

```bash
alias make=make              # for a native Makefile project
alias make=ninja             # for a native ninja project
alias make='cmake --build'   # for all CMake projects
```

When starting to work on a project, all you need to do is `source alias_make.sh` and you can use `make` in blissful ignorance of actually calling `ninja` (well, unless it breaks because they're not the same, of course).

By the way, I frequently use `mak` for such `alias`es or shell `function`s because it saves *yet another* keystroke. Consider dropping the last letter if you think you can overcome your muscle memory.

In closing, let me say that `make` and `ninja` are not the same so every attempt to masquerade one as the other will result in a [leaky abstraction](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/).

Comment: I like this answer, however in modern C++ projects I find the compilation speed to be the way larger weight on the total build time - I have never found that "big" difference between ninja and make in my builds. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It's not Modern C++ projects. It's projects that abuse the "header-only" paradigm. My 5000+ files C++20 project compiles in seconds.

Comment: @Vroomfondel ninja is supposed to be faster in large projects when there's *little or no* recompilation to be done. If you don't need make's rich syntax (e.g. when you're using CMake), ninja is usually the better choice. Having said that, one should always measure before deciding for a tool.

Comment: So `make tests -j32` will spawn 32 `make tests`, right?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Ninja debug info on a break is way cleaner.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher not exactly sure what `make tests -j32`will do. Make will try to run with 32 jobs but there's only one (non-parallelizable) command `ninja tests` so it will probably run that as a single job. I didn't try out, however.