How do I obtain all CMake targets imported within a package's "namespace"?
After executing find_package(mypkg), I should now have all sorts of targets under the mypkg "namespace". Yes, I know there aren't real namespaces in CMake, but targets named mypkg::foo or mypkg::bar etc.
I want to obtain a list of all of these targets. How do I do that?
Note: Assume that no other CMake target in my project begins with mypkg::, including other imported targets.

Just iterate over all targets in your project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211516/programmatically-get-all-targets-in-a-cmake-project, then filter ones started from mypkg::. If you are currently in the CMakeLists.txt which calls find_package(mypkg), then it is sufficient to check only targets in the property BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS for current directory.

If I write this: get_property(my_tgts DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}" PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS), the resulting my_tgts is empty :-(

Oops, sorry, description of the property explicitly says that it doesn't contain IMPORTED targets. You need to read IMPORTED_TARGETS property instead.
